# かも。 か。。。も？　n5 lvl learner

Tags: particle-も, particle-か

G'day guys, i'm back trying to learn a bit of japanese again. haha, i've lost count how many times it is now

変な質問があります。。。
多分

Is there ever a time you can say it like, where there is a slight pause?

E.g.　例え

A:  余裕がないか。。。も知れないから

Maybe, the couple are looking at buying a new car. But with the information they have, it’s uncertain if they can afford it.

B:  その余裕がないか。。。hmmも知らないから

Maybe, the couple are looking at buying a new car.
But. The husband, is BAD at math/numbers(俺も). So he doesn't really know.

The original example was just 余裕がないかも知れないから on it's own with no sort of context.

Please let me know if you want me to Del/or relocate this.
(It's actually pretty intimidating attempting to search through the previous questions. That's just me though).
Thank you for your time and patience

Comment: I recall hearing something like 「問題ないかぁぁもしれない」but not anything with an actual pause in between 「か」and 「もしれない」, for me it sounds a bit weird going from a question to an "affirmative". But I cannot say for sure, a native speaker will be much better for this.

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira Thanks for sharing your experience.

I will search for more example sentences, of all the above. 
どうも。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically かも is treated like one word, and there should be no pause between か and も. If you stopped talking after か for whatever reason, you should repeat at least かも. As long as you treat かも as one word, it's possible to continue the other person's statement and say something like this.

> 「高い？」
> 「かも知れない。」
>
> "Is it expensive?"
> "Maybe."

(Of course it's technically possible to elongate か so that it connects to something after it. Imagine how you can pronounce "maaaaay.............be" as one word, without sounding like "May, Bee". But this rarely happens in reality.)

Comment: Thankyou for your response.
Enjoy your day.